# Can't create the ".ideavimrc"-file which i need for using vim with pycharm

Tags: macos, python, vi

So i wanted to start using vim in PyCharm and use a custom set of keybinds for that. I installed the ideavim plugin inside PyCharm.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-product-as-the-vim-editor.html#vimrc

This manual tells me that im supposed to create a file called ".ideavimrc" in my home directory to add my custom keybind configuration. I cant do that though since my mac wont allow me to create files starting with ".". I am at a loss on what to do.

How can I create this file and save / paste the required contents to follow my guide?

Comment: What happens if you open Terminal and issue the command `touch ~/.ideavimrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolutes best advice I can give you is to get BBEdit and use it as a free text editor to assist with PyCharm (which also is a very nice editor - especially for learning Python).

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bbedit/id404009241

Make your file and then save the file. To choose your home folder press Command-Shift-H (you will see my home / user folder is named Mike from this image) then name it with a period. The app will warn you that the file is hidden, but it will save the file and you can use the app to edit and not have to learn a command-line editor like vi/vim/ed/nano or such. Those are nice, but you can hire BBEdit for free to solve this and focus on your Python learning for now.

[image: saving a hidden file in BBEdit]

(You could also use Textedit to avoid a free app - just paste your contents into a new document and then convert it from rich text to plain text before saving (Command-Shift-T). You have to disable the "add .txt" extension before saving as well.

[image: saving a hidden file in TextEdit]

BBEdit will syntax color python and so many other files and has lots of other goodies you may learn to use.